# JavaScript Code Analysis/Insight Tool

Tags: javascript

While there are several questions in this matter in StackOverflow, none of them address my needs. I would like to know if there is a tool that will among other basic things:

- Show the number of and names of functions (introspection)
- Path/Dependencies

JSHint is more of a stylistic and "best-practices" analysis and doesn't really give me any insight in terms of complexity, quantity or dependencies.

I've searched through node modules, but haven't really seen any that would fit my case, although it's entirely possible I just didn't see it.

Comment: What do you mean with "Path/Dependencies"? And for the number and names of function...you can even `grep` them out via the commandline.

Comment: Path/Dependencies is a common thing to know when you want to refactor code in our out of modules. You want to make sure that no code calls that function in its current location/scope and so forth.

Comment: @Syrahn i am new to node and server side javascript but i have seen many projects that allow you to list dependencies, (maybe just for require.js?? i dont know) one that i have used is `bbb` i dont' know what is powering it though https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb#list-bbb